# How to combine two materials (for package design mockup)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm sorry if this is somehow answered by another question but I'm having trouble finding a suitable answer. There is an incredibly similar question [How can I combine two materials in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33158/how-can-i-combine-two-materials-in-cycles) but I'm not quite sure what to do.

I followed along with [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAhWsUBy3uY) to find out how to uv-map a texture onto a box.

However, I want the box to have a paper/cardboard texture and found a [Procedural cardboard material (cycles)](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/86814).

I'm a bit confused about how to go about giving my box the cardboard texture and then applying a design overtop? It always seems to be one or the other.

I've tried mixing the two with a mix shader which unfortunately doesn't seem to work (it only seems to show the cardboard texture):

[image: node editor]

Below is the cardboard material and above is the image design, transparent black text.

I am using the cycles renderer.

**edit** What is also odd is that both materials seem to show in the `Material` viewport, but not in `Rendered`. Also, in the `Material` viewport, I can imagine the result is not ideal also because it is a blend of the textures rather than the black type sitting on top of the cardboard.

Comment: Try using the alpha output of your text image node as factor of the mix shader node. When the result is Inverted, just swap the shader inputs of the mix shader.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material