# Multiple materials with transparency

Tags: materials, transparency

i have been trying something with no results and after searching the web i could not find a solution, i don´t even know if it´s possible to achieve what i am trying to accomplish. I have one material that i use in several objects and i have a second material png image result of a shadow bake(each object has a different shadow material but they all share the same background material). I would like to use the 2 materials in one object using the shadow on top of the background layer so i can export as a GLB. Can anyone please help me? I know u can assign a material to a specific face or faces of the mesh but it does not work with transparency.

Comment: Do you just want to mix the two materials together on one object?

Comment: Yes thats correct but in a way that one material overlays the other and still being 2 independent materials. Meaning the background shader nodes are separate from the shadow nodes.  Thanks

Comment: like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33158/how-can-i-combine-two-materials-in-cycles ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes something like that but you can only export a GLB in 2.8 if you use the Principled BSDF node and everytime i try to overlay the shadow on top of the background i can only see one or the other. I will keep on trying.  Thanks